# Sending message from one app to al other as admin

Tags: android, ios

I have an app where anyone can download an iOS or android app. No user will have to register or login.

I need to be able for admin users to send notifications to all users if and when new information needs to be delivered. This will be a one way conversation from admin to all users. There may be multiple admins.

What is the best way to handle this? Is push notifications the best and if so what is the best solution? I looked at Parse and it might be a solution.

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

**Parse** and **Urban Airship** are very solid, and likely either will work for your needs.

Another solution is creating your own service  using the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) and Google Cloud Messaging. However, it requires a significant amount of integration time.